# How can I prove that this Linear operator is closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, unbounded-operators, closed-graph

I know that for every infinite dimensional Banach space $X$ admits a linear and discontinuous operator. To prove it, I took a sequence $\{e_n\}_{n\geq1}$ of linearly independent vectors of $X$, then I propose the operator $T:X\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $T(e_n)=n||e_n||.$

Asumming Axiom of Choice, I can complete $\{e_n\}_{n\geq1}$ to a basis, and extend $T$ to a linear operator $\lambda$ such that, $\lambda(e_n)=T(e_n)$ and $\lambda(E_k)=0$, if $E_k$ is an element of the basis but different from every $e_n$. So I claim the operator $\lambda$ is a linear unbounded operator, i.e. a linear non-continuous operator.

My question is... How can I prove that the operator $\lambda$ indeed is a closed operator?

Every comment would be appreciated, even if I made a mistake writing my "proof" of the existence of a discontinuous linear operator.

Comment: Your construction is fine but why do you think $\lambda$ is a closed operator? It certainly is not closed. If it is closed it would be bounded by Closed Graph Theorem.

Comment: I don't think its closed. WLOG $\|e_n\| = 1$ and consider the sequence $e_n/\sqrt{n}$. This is a convergent sequence but $\lambda(e_n/\sqrt{n})$ is not.

Comment: Ohhhhhh I I see, certainly I forgot that from the closed graph theorem, @KaviRamaMurthy.

Comment: And also you are right with that counter-example @RishiSonthalia, thanks for your answers!!!

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to prove it but forgot elemental things about closed operators, blinded by the necessity of proving.
Via definition: Isn't closed because, $e_n/\sqrt{n}$ is a convergent sequence but $\lambda(e_n/\sqrt{n}$ isn't. (ANSWER BY @Rishi Sonthalia, thanks).

Via closed graph theorem: Isn't closed because, if it is closed, then $\lambda$ must be bounded but we already prove that $\lambda$ indeed is unbounded. (ANSWER BY @KaviRamaMurthy).